# Attach data to a select object, query in event listener, in HTML/javascript

Tags: html, css

I want to query a target for some data (that I set at runtime) in my event listener.  I'm creating select elements at runtime like so:

```
        <select id = "someid"  >
            <% list.each { |x| %>

                 <option> <%= x %></option>

            <% } %>
        </select>
```

In my event listener I would like to get not only "event.target.id", but also "event.target.some_data_field_that_was_set_at_runtime"

Would I create a class in CSS that extends select and add my own data field, or something? Sorry, I don't know HTML/CSS too well, if so could you give an example of how to write that class and use it?  Thanks!

Comment: That looks like ASP. Is it? It's not very useful when only working with HTML/CSS, which is what a browser sees (the final source).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By "runtime" I assume you mean the standard: when your (looks like ASP) code runs on the server.  On page-load in the browser is a different answer.

Also, the `option` value is not enough?

Anyway, just have your code set a `rel` attribute for the `select` element.  Or use [**HTML 5 data- Attributes**](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/).

For Example:

```
<select name="cars" rel="European only" -data-linked-input-id="carsInput">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Cool, thanks, I got the html 5 data attributes to work.  I actually want to embed 2 pieces of data (I should have said up front), and this method works well.  Is there any downside to using html5, like compatibility issues?  Sorry, I'm just sort of learning about all this stuff, much appreciated.

Comment: I can't think of any downside to use data attributes like this.  If you don't use an HTML5 `DOCTYPE` then you will get some otherwise harmless validation warnings (If you even validate (you should)).  I've not heard of any browser that misbehaves when an HTML5 `DOCTYPE` is used, but I wouldn't be surprised if IE 6 did.